# Make form on Blazor submit

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server side form I have created right here

```
<EditForm Model="formValues" OnValidSubmit="@DownloadExcelFile">

            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <MatThemeProvider Theme="@theme">
                <div class="row text-center">

                    <div class="col-6 text-right pb-3">
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="row formRow">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center pb-2">
                        <MatSelect Label="Region" @bind-Value="@formValues.Region">
                            @foreach (var region in Regions)
                                    {
                                <MatOptionString Value="@region.Id.ToString()">@region.Description</MatOptionString>
                                    }


                        </MatSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.Region)" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right pb-2">
                        <MatSelect Label="Manual Key" Id="allowManuallyKeyedTxns" @bind-Value="@formValues.AllowManuallyKeyedTxns">
                            <MatOptionString Value="1">Yes</MatOptionString>
                            <MatOptionString Value="0">No</MatOptionString>


                        </MatSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.AllowManuallyKeyedTxns)" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-6 text-left pb-2">
                        <MatSelect Label="Refund Exemption" Id="refundExemption" @bind-Value="@formValues.RefundExcemption">
                            <MatOptionString Value="1">Yes</MatOptionString>
                            <MatOptionString Value="0">No</MatOptionString>




                        </MatSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.RefundExcemption)" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right pb-2">
                        <MatSelect Label="Advice Exemption" Id="adviceExemption" @bind-Value="@formValues.AdviceExemption">
                            <MatOptionString Value="1">Yes</MatOptionString>
                            <MatOptionString Value="0">No</MatOptionString>




                        </MatSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.AdviceExemption)" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-left pb-2">
                        <MatSelect Label="Tip Adjustment" Id="tipAdjustment" @bind-Value="@formValues.TipAdjustment">
                            <MatOptionString Value="1">Yes</MatOptionString>
                            <MatOptionString Value="0">No</MatOptionString>




                        </MatSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.TipAdjustment)" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right pb-2">
                        <MatDatePicker Label="Start Date" @bind-Value="@formValues.TxnDate" EnableTime="false" Format="MMM/dd/yyyy"></MatDatePicker>

                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.TxnDate)" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-left pb-2">
                        <MatDatePicker Label="End Date" @bind-Value="@formValues.TxnEndDate" EnableTime="false" Format="MMM/dd/yyyy"></MatDatePicker>

                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formValues.TxnEndDate)" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <div class="col-12 p-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
                                Export to Excel&nbsp;
                                <i class="fa fa-file-excel" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </MatThemeProvider>
        </EditForm>
```

And a method that on submit will query from a database and create an excel file. As you can see here

```
    async Task DownloadExcelFile()
    {
        DownloadExcel(formValues.Region, formValues.TxnDate, formValues.TxnEndDate, formValues.AllowManuallyKeyedTxns, formValues.AdviceExemption, formValues.RefundExcemption, formValues.TipAdjustment, formValues.isManuallyKeyed, formValues.isAdviceExemption, formValues.isRefundExemption, formValues.isTipAdjustment);

    }
    public void DownloadExcel(string Region, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate, string ManuallyKeyedTxsn, string AdviceExemption, string RefundExemption, string TipAdjustment, bool isManuallyKeyed, bool isAdvice, bool isRefund, bool isTip)
    {
        var RegionId = Convert.ToInt64(Region);
        var ExcelFile = OreService.OreExportToExcel(RegionId, StartDate, EndDate, ManuallyKeyedTxsn, AdviceExemption, RefundExemption, TipAdjustment, isManuallyKeyed, isAdvice, isRefund, isTip);
        string excelName;

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("POS Terminal Access Audit Report");



            workSheet.Cells["A2:A2"].LoadFromCollection(from a in ExcelFile select new { MerchantID = a.MerchantRecord.ToString(), MerchantName = a.Name.ToString(), DoingBusinessAs = a.LegalName, MerchantCategoryCode = a.Mccrecord, MerchantCategoryCodeDescription = a.MccDescription, a.AddressLine1, a.AddressLine2, a.AddressLine3, a.AddressLine4, a.City, a.PhoneNumber, a.EmailAddress, a.TerminalId, TerminalType = a.TermType, CurrentManuallyKeyed = a.ManuallyKeyedString, ChangedManuallyKeyed = a.AllowManuallyKeyedChangedValueString, ChangedManuallyKeyedDate = a.AllowManuallyKeyedChangedDate, a.ExpireByPassCreditDate, CurrentCreditByPassValue = a.BypassCreditString, ChangedCreditBypassValue = a.RefundBypassChangedString, RefundBypassChangedDate = a.RefundBypassChangedDate, RefundBypassExpiryDate = a.RefundBypassEndDate, CurrentAdviceBypassValue = a.BypassAdviceString, ChangedAdviceBypassValue = a.BypassAdviceChangedString, AdviceBypassChangedDate = a.AdviceBypassChangedDate, CurrentTip = a.TipString, TipChangedValue = a.TipChangedString, a.TipChangedDate }, true);
            workSheet.DefaultColWidth = 25;
            excelName = $"POS Terminal Access Audit Report-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.xlsx";




            JsRuntime.SaveAs(excelName, package.GetAsByteArray());
        }
```

Now I can't for the life of me figure out why this form on work on submit. I have made breakpoints and when I click the submit button the DownloadExcelFile task is never activated I can't tell if I have made the form incorrectly or my task or method to create the excel file are at fault. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an @ on the onValidSubmit method on the EditForm. What you want is probably something like. That might work for .Net 6 but perhaps you might want to try:

```
<EditForm Model="formValues" OnValidSubmit="()=>DownloadExcelFile()">
...
```

or

```
<EditForm Model="formValues" OnValidSubmit="DownloadExcelFile">
...
```